# Django: File upload not working with Ajax

Tags: django, jquery

I don't understand why but if I try to upload file via ajax it does not work but with regular request it does.

Printed the request.FILES.

```
#For ajax request
<MultiValueDict: {}>

#For regular request
<MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: IMG_3056.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>

#Here's my front-end and back-end code
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
function submitForm(target, form){
    $.ajax({
        url:form.attr('action'),
        type:'post',
        data:form.serialize(),
        dataType:"html",
        error:function(data, status, xhr){
            error();
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            loading();
        },
        success:function(data, status, xhr){
            $(target).html(data);
        },
        complete:function(){
            loadingDone();
        }
    });
}

#views.py

def file_upload(request):
    doc_form = DocumentForm(user = request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        doc_form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user)
        print request.FILES
        if doc_form.is_valid():
            document = doc_form.save()
    return render_to_response("create_doc.html", {                                                                  'doc_form':doc_form, 
}, context_instance = template.RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using this [jquery form submit plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started), I think it will manage to send the FILE to the server like you need.

(It works for me for a PHP server side, no reason why it wont work for you too)

Answer (score 3):

Uploading files with regular jQuery's AJAX does not work. See some of these links for help:

http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/file-uploading-over-ajax-using-html5

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Basically there is a new API in HTML 5 for dealing with files or the old school way is using an iFrame/Flash. Personally I used [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) on a project a couple of months ago.

Comment: Thanks, I din't knew jquery ajax function doesn't support multipart data transfer